# Control invocation of a method call after new object creation

Tags: java

I have a scheduled method call which on the scheduled time calls the following method:

```
private void doSomething(Map<String, String> someArguments) throws CustomException {
  MyEnum runType = getRunType(someArguments);
  switch (runType) {
        case FRUIT:
             new FruitClass().workNow();
             break;

        case VEGETABLE:
             new VegetableClass().workNow();
             break;

        default:
            // log that the type is not known 
      }
   }
```

The method signature of `workNow` is like:

```
workNow() throws CustomException
```

`workNow` method runs for several minutes and does some work. My issue is, when one `workNow` for `FRUIT` (or `VEGETABLE`) is going on and another invoke happens with same type (`FRUIT` for example), it creates a new `FruitClass` instance and starts executing its `workNow` parallelly.

How do I control this behavior? I want the second invocation through second object to wait until first `workNow` through first object is not complete.

To clarify:

- Parallel invocation of `FRUIT` and `VEGETABLE` is fine. I want to control parallel invocation of same type. Two or more `FRUIT` or two or more `VEGETABLE`.
- I can not make `FruitClass` and `VegetableClass` as singletons. I need some wrapping code around `new` to work how I want.

Comment: Why not make `FruitClass` a singleton class and synchronize `workNow`? Alternatively, you can make a single-thread pool per runType and use that.

Comment: Is this code multithreaded? I assume so but you are not mentionig it.

Comment: @NiVeR: Yes. Do something can be called at two places at the same time.

Comment: Ya use a singleton implementation for the FruitClass and synchronise the `workNow()` with a lock. Do you need code help ?

Comment: @ernest_k: No. I can not modify the existing code. I need to wrap something around the "new" call to make it work how I want. Hence the problem.

Comment: @vizsatiz: I cannot change the classes. Modified the question to clear that.

Comment: @Nik what can you modify?

Comment: Perhaps, you can wrap the individual `case`s logic around `synchronized(current class object){}` block

Comment: @AdityaGupta: How will surrounding "create new instance and call method on that instance" with synchronized help? Its not that "this" will wait for process method to finish before going out of synchronized block.

Comment: Added working solutions in my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the synchronisation on a class object, and this will be enough to avoid creation of another class until finished:

```
private void doSomething(Map<String, String> someArguments) {
    MyEnum runType = getRunType(someArguments);
    switch (runType) {
        case FRUIT:
            synchronized (FruitClass.class){
                new FruitClass().workNow();
            }
            break;

        case VEGETABLE:
            synchronized (VegetableClass.class){
                new VegetableClass().workNow();
            }
            break;

        default:
            // log that the type is not known 
    }
}
```

`synchronized` on class object uses the class instance as a monitor. 
Class object is actually a singleton (the object representing the class metadata at runtime), and only one thread can be in this block.

Comment: Didn't know something like this is there.. This sounds interesting.. Could you please elaborate a bit..

Comment: I added more explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of solutions, I could think of :

## Solution-1

```
static final String FRUIT = "FRUIT";
static final String VEGETABLE = "VEGETABLE";

private void doSomething(Map<String, String> someArguments) {
    MyEnum runType = getRunType(someArguments);
        switch (runType) {
            case FRUIT:
                synchronized (FRUIT){
                    new FruitClass().workNow();
                }
                break;

            case VEGETABLE:
                synchronized (VEGETABLE){
                    new VegetableClass().workNow();
                }
                break;

            default:
                // log that the type is not known 
        }
}
```

This might be better than using `class` objects, since they would be heavier and consume memory.

## Solution-2

This is an enhancement to the Solution-1, incase there are multiple cases and class level `String`s are not desired.

```
private void doSomething(Map<String, String> someArguments) {
    MyEnum runType = getRunType(someArguments);
    synchronized(runType.toString().intern()) {//This prevents 2 FRUITs or 2 VEGETABLEs from entering
        switch (runType) {
            case FRUIT:
                    new FruitClass().workNow();
                break;

            case VEGETABLE:
                    new VegetableClass().workNow();
                break;

            default:
                // log that the type is not known 
        }
    }
}
```

Both are tested in a slightly different example, but make the point.

Answer (score 0):

There are surely many ways to address this. I believe the simplest is to use single-thread pools for each type of task:

```
//one pool per runType
private final ExecutorService fruitService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private final ExecutorService vegService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

And then:

```
private void doSomething(Map<String, String> someArguments) {
    MyEnum runType = getRunType(someArguments);

    CompletableFuture<Void> result;

    switch (runType) {
    case FRUIT:
        result = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> 
                new FruitClass().workNow(), fruitService)
                .exceptionally((exception) -> {
                    if (exception instanceof CustomException) {
                        System.out.println("Failed with custom exception...");
                    }

                    return null; // returning Void
                });
        break;

    case VEGETABLE:
        result = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> 
                new VegetableClass().workNow(), vegService)
                .exceptionally((exception) -> {
                    if (exception instanceof CustomException) {
                        System.out.println("Failed with custom exception...");
                    }

                    return null; // returning Void
                });

        break;

    default:
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    result.join();
}
```

This simply forces concurrent calls to wait for resources and 2 tasks of the same type won't run concurrently.

It offers the additional benefit of asynchronous execution, although you can explicitly block to wait for results if needed.

Comment: I tried this. Issue is, workNow may throw CustomException, which travels up through doSomething.. i.e. doSomething throws CustomException.. doing this is forcing me to surround new call with try catch... how to deal with that ?

Comment: @Nik I changed it slightly to use completablefuture. I believe that the cause is not wrapped in completionexception from reading the javadocs, but you may just need to test the propagated exception object.