# Terminating a thread about to go to wait state for a Synchronized resource

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a scheduled method call which on the scheduled time calls the following method:

```
private void doSomething(Map<String, String> someArguments) throws CustomException {
  MyEnum runType = getRunType(someArguments);
  switch (runType) {
        case FRUIT:
             new FruitClass().workNow();
             break;

        case VEGETABLE:
             new VegetableClass().workNow();
             break;

        default:
            // log that the type is not known 
      }
   }
```

The method signature of `workNow` is like:

```
workNow() throws CustomException
```

`workNow` method runs for several minutes and does some work. My issue was, when one `workNow` for `FRUIT` (or `VEGETABLE`) was going on and another invoke happened with same type (`FRUIT` for example), it created a new `FruitClass` instance and started executing its `workNow` parallelly.

I resolved it as:

```
private void doSomething(Map<String, String> someArguments) {
    MyEnum runType = getRunType(someArguments);
    switch (runType) {
        case FRUIT:
            synchronized (FruitClass.class){
                new FruitClass().workNow();
            }
            break;

        case VEGETABLE:
            synchronized (VegetableClass.class){
                new VegetableClass().workNow();
            }
            break;

        default:
            // log that the type is not known 
    }
}
```

from answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52943068/887235).

This works fine. But it builds a queue of waiting threads on the synchronized class which acquire lock as soon as the previous thread releases it.

Just to enhance my knowledge, is there a way to determine that when a thread comes in and sees a lock on the class, instead of going into wait, it just gets terminated.

In other words, "I am here to do `workNow`. Let me get a lock on `FruitClass`. Oh! some other thread has the lock already and is doing `workNow`. I need not do anything. Terminate."

How to achieve this here?

**Edit 1:**

**From answer below:**

```
final Lock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();

private void doSomething(Map<String, String> someArguments) {
    MyEnum runType = getRunType(someArguments);
    switch (runType) {
        case FRUIT:
            if(reentrantLock.tryLock()) {
               try {
                   new FruitClass().workNow();
                } finally {
                   reentrantLock.unlock();
                }
            } else {
              // do nothing and terminate
            }
            break;

        case VEGETABLE:
            synchronized (VegetableClass.class){
                new VegetableClass().workNow();
            }
            break;

        default:
            // log that the type is not known 
    }
}
```

However, this is not going to work obviously. As this will just instantiate new `FruitClass`, call process and release the lock.

As my original problem says, I want to lock the creation of new object itself, if a object is already created and is doing `workNow`.

How do I achieve that with Locks?

I don't know if something like this is possible:

```
final Lock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock(FruitClass.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've the question right you're using for more "fine-grained" methods to work with java synchronization. Using "synchronized" is not just flexible enough.

One Way to solve this is using Locks offered by `java.util.concurrent.locks` package.

Locks there in particular offer `tryLock` method, that just tries to obtain the lock but if its already possessed by another thread it just won't enter a critical section, you can try for a certain period of time or move on immediately, an API is flexible enough to allow it.

Comment: I'm still confused about the edit, sorry. Suppose you have 2 threads. The first thread reaches "tryLock" line, and assuming no other threads are running at this time it acquires a lock (tryLock returns true) and enters the 'if" - so fruit class gets instantiated. Now the second thred that also calls doSomething reaches the line with 'tryLock' however it immediately returns false, so it doesn't even create a FruitClass. The effect is that only one thread does the job, others just bypass and do nothing.

Comment: Oh! My Bad.. you are right.. this should work.. let me give it a try.. thanks for responding!

Comment: Cool, glad to hear! Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful ;)